# Limiting number of rows in a listview and adding a new column

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i'm filling a list view with records from a datatable i need to limit the number of rows in the list view to 5 and when the records are more than 5 i need to create a new column in the list view to display the records...

that's how i'm filling the list view:

```
     Private Sub ShowDataInLvw(ByVal data As DataTable, ByVal lvw As ListView)
    lvw.View = View.Details
    lvw.GridLines = True
    lvw.Columns.Clear()
    lvw.Items.Clear()
    For Each col As DataColumn In data.Columns
        lvw.Columns.Add(col.ToString)
    Next

    For Each row As DataRow In data.Rows
        Dim lst As ListViewItem
        lst = lvw.Items.Add(row(0))
        For i As Integer = 1 To data.Columns.Count - 1
            lst.SubItems.Add(row(i))
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

note that my datatable has only 1 column and i'm using vb.net 2010

any help?

Comment: If you only want to display a single property for each item, and you want it to wrap to multiple columns when there are too many items to fit in one column, why not just change the `View` from `Details` to `List`?

Comment: If Steven's question don't help maybe you can think about checkingi the length of lvw.items.count? and if its an increment of 5 add your new column?